# How to perform Batch Writes sequentially in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Batch Write that looks like this:

```
let newChatDocument = db.collection("chats").document()
let newMessageDocument = newChatDocument.collection("messages").document()

batch.setData(["chatName": "Test Chat"], forDocument: newChatDocument)
batch.setData(["sender": "user1", "content": "Hello!"], forDocument: newMessageDocument)
batch.commit()
```

I recently read that Batch Writes don't happen sequentially so I don't know what the outcome of this Batch Write would be. Since the `"messages"` collection is a subcollection of a `"chat"` document, I would need the chat document to be created first.

Can anyone tell me what the outcome of this Batch Write would be (would it fail or would it succeed) with a small explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best way is test it in real world, and check what happens, and how. And here check this link about more info. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the "messages" collection is a subcollection of a "chat" document, I would need the chat document to be created first.

This is actually not true.  Parent documents don't need to exist prior to creating documents in subcollections under that document.  Documents are not "containers" for nested documents in the same way that folders work in a traditional computer filesystem.  Each and every document exists fully separate from other documents with no dependencies between them.

The final result of this batch write is that your two document will be created, and there will be no errors or unexpected results.  This should be easy to try for yourself.